# Move an image in a div html5 css3

Tags: html, css

If I would to move the image like 50px from the top of the div and 50px from the left (I am not talking about animate, is it padding I should use?)

```
<header>
<img src="logo.png" alt="" />
</header>

header {
 width...
height:
background: (url)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the image as background:

```
<header></header>
```

css:

```
header {
  background-image:url(logo.png) 50px 50px;
}
```

Or alternatively, use `absolute` positioning:

```
<header>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" />
</header>
```

css:

```
header { position:relative; }
header img {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
```

Comment: No, I already have a header image... I have a "logo" image over it that I want to move 50 px from the left and top on the header img :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, if you want could you explain how position stuff work? No need tho but would be appreciated, I mark your answer as good!

Comment: @John: Sure, you must read this article: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution that you are looking for is:

header {
padding: 50px 0px 0px 50px
}

This will create padding of 50px from the top and 50px from the left of the header

Thanks,
A.